# What is the property accessor for a mask on SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, svg, properties, mask

I've been going through documentation, but cannot seem to find an answer to the following question...

I want to add a `mask` attribute to a `circle` element in my project, but would like to avoid `circle.setAttribute()` if I can.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<circle />

/* JS */
let node = document.querySelector(`circle`);

circle.id = `foo`;
circle.mask = `url(#bar)`; // This isn't valid...?
circle.setAttribute(`mask`, `url(#bar)`); // What I want to avoid doing. But substitutes the invalid line above.

/* Resulting HTML after JS fires */
<circle id="foo" mask="url(#bar)" />
```

What is the property accessor for a `mask` on SVG elements? Does one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mask is a mapped CSS attribute so you can set it via circle.style.mask = ... that won't give you quite the specificity of an attribute but it's the closest you can get without using setAttribute.

Comment: It's amazing how silly a well-crafted, concise  answer can make you feel ;) Thank you!